# Schema for json message in aiokafka

Tags: json, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, kafka-python

How can I add a schema for json message in `aiokafka`? Kafka Connect cannot work without it.

```
import asyncio
import json
import random

import aiokafka
from faker import Faker


def serializer(value):
    return json.dumps(value).encode()


async def produce():
    fake = Faker(['ru_RU'])
    producer = aiokafka.AIOKafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092', value_serializer=serializer)
    await producer.start()

    try:
        while True:
            message = {
                'name': fake.first_name(),
                'surname': fake.last_name(),
                'age': random.randint(20, 30)
            }
            await producer.send("mytopic", message)
    finally:
        await producer.stop()


asyncio.run(produce())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Kafka Connect cannot work without it

It *can* if you have `value.converter.schemas.enable=false`. Whether you need a schema depends on specific connectors, not Connect itself.

---

If you are not able to change your serializer, for example, to the Avro one from the `confluent_kafka` library, then you need to provide `schema` and `payload` as part of *each message* on your own

e.g.

```
message = { 'schema': { ... }, 
            'payload': {
              'name': fake.first_name(),
              'surname': fake.last_name(),
              'age': random.randint(20, 30)
            }
        }
```

More info:  [Kafka Connect Deep Dive – Converters and Serialization Explained](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-converters-serialization-explained/)